# MVC Linq Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: c#, linq

Good day. I have a Linq code that when run, shows this error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But when I try to put all the same values into SQL, it works fine. Is there something wrong with my LINQ code?

THE OUTPUT IN SQL
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgtIh.png)

**CODE**

```
 var list = (from R in db.vwEtracs_Receipt
                    join RI in db.vwEtracs_ReceiptItem on R.objid equals RI.parentid
                    join IA in db.vwEtracs_IncomeAccount on RI.acctid equals IA.objid
                    join M in db.vwtbl_Motor
                         on new { motor_no = R.remarks.Substring(5), operator_id = R.payerId }
                         equals new { motor_no = M.motor_no, operator_id = M.operator_id } into M_join
                    from M in M_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join F in db.tbl_Franchise on R.objid equals F.or_id into F_join
                    from F in F_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join B in db.tbl_Make on M.brand_id equals B.id

                    where
                    IA.objid == "FTFA00000238" &&
                    R.voidId == null &&
                    R.remarks != null 
                    orderby R.txndate descending
                    select new PayedViewModel
                    {
                        application_no = F.application_no,
                        remarks = R.remarks,
                        serialno = R.serialno,
                        payername = R.payername,
                        payeraddress = R.payeraddress,
                        motor_no = M.motor_no,
                        chassis_no = M.chassis_no,
                        plate_no = M.plate_no,
                        brand_name = B.Make,
                        motor_id = M.motor_id,
                        year = R.txndate.Value.Year.ToString(),
                        mtop = F.mtop,
                        franchise_id = F.franchise_id
                    }
                    ).Distinct();
```

Usually the error shows in this line, `motor_no = R.remarks.Substring(5)` because when I change it to 4, the code runs smoothly. I tried manually checking all the data in the db but found nothing suspicious nor anything that will give it negative value.

At this point I don't know what is wrong with my code or db. Thank you.

Comment: probably you have at least one record that the length is smaller than 5 characters

Comment: @ElyasEsna I don't know. Because when coding in SQL nothing wrong happens. The code works perfectly. Please see my updated post above with the photo.

Comment: Could it be that .NET runs with 0 indexed strings and SQL with 1 indexed? - you mention 4 is okay but 5 is not?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Does that mean that one data could have an index or space in it?

Comment: According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_left.asp) "If the number exceeds the number of characters in string, it returns string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen because your database have string which it's length less than 5 
make sure that all R.remarks.length are more than 5
may be you need to do check or something like this :

```
R.remarks.Length > 5 ? R.remarks.Substring(5) : R.remarks
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks Sr. But still I am curious as to why I can't find the data that has been giving me the error.

Comment: try to select all values from that column in SQL and see if their are values which it's length is less than 5 or may be null i'm not sure

Comment: I tried adding this code in my SQL, (LEN(LEFT(R.remarks, 4))>5), but still nothing appears

Comment: you also need to check in SQL if your string length is more than 5 or not  something like this                                                                                    SELECT p.ColumnName ,ABRESC =
   CASE WHEN LEN(p.ColumnName ) > 4 
       THEN SUBSTRING(p.ColumnName , 1, 4)
       ELSE  p.ColumnName END
from tableName p

Comment: Ok sr. I will try to look for it. Thanks for the help